# Restoring error database in use in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, restore

I want to restore a database with this query, but an error occurs telling that the database is in use.
What should I do?

This is my code:

```
RESTORE DATABASE db_languageLab 
FROM DISK = N'E:\E\db_languageLab_1394_8_15.bak'
WITH FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 10
```

Comment: Are you doing this in Management Studio, and you're currently connected to this database you're trying to restore? Do a `use master;` before this to switch to the `master` database before restoring another database

Comment: yes i am using master

Answer (score 0):

Database is 'in use' error occurs when some other session/user is connected. Looking simple? But not. 
Whenever this happens, I just restart my database service, from services, or by right click on server name in object explorer.

But some times, it doesn't work. I realized after striking head several times that I set my database as default. By default 'master' is your default database. Restoring database process uses default database to restore you own database, so if you have same database as default, it will always pop the same 'in use' error.

To set master back to default (if your current db is set to default mistakenly or by need) run the following command

```
Exec sp_defaultdb @loginame='sa', @defdb='master'
```

Now it will have 'master' database to 'plan and process' restoring for 'YourDB'.